# Import command causes error "net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, linux, ckeditor, importerror

I'm trying to import a module into CKEditor5. Here's the import statement:

`import Alignment from '/mnt/randomdirectories/web/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-alignment/src/alignment.js';`

I'm certain this file path is correct, however I'm greeted with the following error in the console:
`net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID`

I'm not sure what I could do be doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

In my case ckeditor's SSL was expired and it stopped working by showing the same error next day it was working fine.
On local, I check CDN by calling it from HTTP so it worked on local that's how I verified the ckeditor's SSL was expired